# Angular: trigger a interval observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

How can I trigger an interval-observable to perform its action outside the defined interval but keep the interval running as defined?

**Sample:**

Intervall is 10s. I like to call *doit* not only in the intervall but also if an event occours - lets say a button-click.

Sure I can call doit in the button-handler but is there a way I can do it with the obervable (e.g. sort of *obs.trigger ()*)??

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit
{
    private obs : any;   // the observable instance

    ngOnInit ()
    {
        this.obs = Observable.interval (10 * 1000)
            .startWith (0)
            .subscribe ((n) => 
            {
                doit ();
            });
    }

    doit ()
    {
       // some action
    }

    clicked ()
    {
        doit ();   // works but I am looking for a way to do it with obs
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the interval to reset when the manual event is triggered?

Comment: No, but if it is also fine.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think that is possible as , you create observable based on interval .

But if you want observable than you can create it like this

```
<button (click)="obs.next($event)">

private obs = new Subject();
public obs$ = this.obs.asObservable();
```

and than just combine observable like this

```
first.concat(second).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

So I am suggesting create two oberservable and than combine them. you already have one and create one more for button click and than combine them.

---

```
<button (click)="obs.next($event)">

private obsButtonClick = new Subject();
public obs$ = this.obsButtonClick.asObservable();

ngOnInit ()
{
    this.obs = Observable.interval (10 * 1000)
        .startWith (0);

     this.obs.concat(obsButtonClick).subscribe ((n) => 
        {
            doit ();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [merge](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) operator to combine two observables. Your interval plus a fromEvent click observable.

```
Observable.merge(
    Observable.interval(10 * 1000),
    Observable.fromEvent(this.myButton.nativeElement, 'click')
)
.startWith(0)
.subscribe(...)
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxlylh?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) demoing this.

Answer (score -1):

I see if I just perform

```
clicked ()
{
  this.obs.next ();
}
```

it is working as I expect.

Is there a negative impact I do not see?
Because your answers are slightly more complex and I am afraid I miss something?

Comment: All of these answers technically work. I think it comes down to conciseness. To me, your original solution is how I would implement the functionality. It is the clearest. On interval do this, on click do this.

Comment: I think the subject approach is overkill for the use case. The merge + fromEvent approach avoids angular event handling. For the obs.next approach, I don't believe I've seen anyone access the next method of a subscription before. not sure of the reason behind this.